# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't suspend when idle

Tags: suspend, idle

On my laptop Asus the system doesn't go to sleep when inactive. In settings, the sleep is set to 10 minutes for battery and AC power when inactive.
Yet, Ubuntu can into suspend when closing the lid ; the command `systemctl suspend` work without root and the updates are up to date. Only the suspend when idle doesn't work.

Kernel version and others data to help :
https://pastebin.com/1bzCCZJe

Answer (score 1):

I dont get the full sleep to mem even though I made changes via the power manager.  This is an old issue perhaps with the display manager.  But its so easy to fix that not worth it to try out the workaround/attempts from various stackoverflow pages.

Tried all of the solutions here except for changing display manager.  On my LG gram Ubuntu 19, ended up running my own script to suspend. see https://github.com/vivekpathak/tools/blob/master/suspend.py

Also impovements to iwlwifi config help with energy consuption (details here : https://superuser.com/a/1541805/1163126 )

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on an Ideapad U530.
Solved it by setting the below inactive keys manually in **org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power**:
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout (I set this to 600)
sleep-inactive-ac-type (I set this to 'suspend')

This solved the inactive sleep issue when the system is plugged in, but I'm still having this problem when on battery power...

Comment: tried the above to get ubuntu 19.* on lg gram to sleep - but cant get it to sleep on idle.   ended up writing my own script at https://github.com/vivekpathak/tools/blob/master/suspend.py and running it via startup applications

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me.

1. Install `gdm`.
2. Set default display manager to `gdm` (`/etc/X11/default-display-manager`).
3. Reboot.
4. Optionally, remove `lightdm`.

Comment: anyone has tried the above please comment.  i recall the display manager also has issues properly suspending to mem (i ended up in "software sleep" which also takes up a lot of energy and not suitable for laptop)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Kubuntu 16.04), the problem was that in System Settings > Energy Saving, although "Suspend session" was checked and set to 5 minutes, the dropdown menu next to the time value was blank. After picking "suspend" from that dropdown, suspend on inactivity now works again for me.